# How to implement CRS model in the real world?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, multiparty-computation

Traditionally, I think that implementing the CRS (common reference string) model in the real world is usually through a trusted third party or running a distributed protocol. Are there specific papers on this that I can refer to? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does the R in your question stand for "random" or "reference"?

Comment: "reference", I'm so sorry for this confusion!

Comment: I think Diffie Hellman is a trivial example it can be extended to Multi Party Diffie Hellman but it doesn't have good efficiency.

Comment: Depending on the type of setup needed, Multiparty computation (MPC) can help. For example, see how ZCash ([https://z.cash/technology/paramgen/) went at it (including further "defense in-depth" mechanisms).

Comment: @JAAAY this only works for the common random string model AFAIK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct: CRS can be realized by a set of trusted parties.

To my knowledge, the closest reference to a practical solution to a CRS is the one that [Zerocash](http://zerocash-project.org/media/pdf/zerocash-extended-20140518.pdf) uses, and that we can read from: [Updatable and Universal Common Reference
Strings with Applications to zk-SNARKs](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/280.pdf).

A similar construction is the correlated randomness setting, an excellent reading about the last one is this [On the Power of Correlated Randomness in Secure Computation](https://www.iacr.org/archive/tcc2013/77850598/77850598.pdf).